Understanding why two definitions of "well-founded relation" are equivalent.
I do not understand why it says "equivalently" here:

A binary relation $R$ on a set $X$ is said to be well-founded if there is no infinite
chain $x_1, . . . , x_n, . . .$ in $X$ such that $x_{n+1}\:R\:x_n$ for all $n.$ Equivalently, if the only
subset $S \subset X$ satisfying $$\forall x(\forall y, y\:R\:x \implies y \in S) \implies x \in S$$ is $S = X.$

I understand that it means each definition implies the other, but I can't figure out how.

@CameronBuie But I do not follow how exactly. Could you compose an answer out of it ?

Can you see how $x_{n+1}$ and $y$ play the same role in the two characterizations?

Why the equivalence-relations tag? I don't see anything about equivalence relations in the question.

As it turns out, depending on what is meant by "chain," the two conditions as written may not be equivalent.
If by "chain," we mean "set totally ordered by $R$," then they are not equivalent. To see why, take any $a,$ let $X=\{a\},$ and let $R=\bigl\{\langle a,a\rangle\bigr\}.$ Since $X$ is finite, then there definitely exists no sequence of points $x_n$ of $X$ whose range is an infinite chain under the relation $R.$ Thus, $R$ is well-founded on $X$ under this interpretation of the first definition.
On the other hand, consider the set $S=\emptyset,$ and note that the following is false: $$\forall y\in X, y\:R\:x\implies y\in S.$$ Thus, the following is vacuously true: $$\forall x\in X,\bigl(\forall y\in X,y\:R\:x\implies y\in S\bigr)\implies x\in S.$$ Since $S$ is a proper subset of $X,$ then $R$ fails to be well-founded on $X$ in the sense of the second definition.

Now, if by "chain" you simply meant "sequence," then we can do better.
We can even prove equivalence with yet a third definition (which I personally find to be more beneficial for intuition):

We say that a binary relation $R$ on a set $X$ is well-founded if for every non-empty subset $A$ of $X,$ there is some $x\in A$ which is a minimal element of $A$ with respect to $R.$ By this, we mean that $$\forall A\subseteq X,\bigl(A\neq\emptyset\implies\exists x\in S:\forall y\in A,\neg[y\:R\:x]\bigr).$$ For brevity, we'll say that such an $x$ is "$R$-minimal in $A.$"

Note that if $R$ is a well-founded binary relation on a set $X,$ then $R$ is necessarily asymmetric--that is, there can exist no $a,b$ such that both $a\:R\:b$ and $b\:R\:a.$ (Can you see why?) Such an $R$ must also be irreflexive--that is, there can exist no $a$ such that $a\:R\:a.$ (Can you see why?) Consequently, among transitive relations, every well-founded binary relation is a strict partial order (although we sometimes confusingly refer to a non-strict partial order as "well-founded" when its strict version is well-founded, as in this post).
To see why the first definition is equivalent to the third definition, we need to make use of the following weak Choice Principle:

Given a non-empty set $P$ that is partially ordered by a relation $\sqsubseteq$ and having the property that for every subset $C$ of $P,$ if $C$ is totally ordered by $\sqsubseteq$ then $C$ is finite, we have that there is some $x$ that is $\sqsupset$-minimal in $P.$

Proof Outline: On the one hand, suppose that $R$ is well-founded on $X$ in the sense of the third definition. If there existed an infinite sequence $\langle x_n\rangle_{n=1}^\infty$ of elements of $X$ such that $x_{n+1}\:R\:x_n$ for all positive integers $n,$ then the set $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb Z_{>0}\}$ would be a non-empty subset of $X$ with no $R$-minimal element, contradicting the third definition. Therefore, no such infinite sequence exists, and so the first definition holds.
On the other hand, suppose that $R$ is well-founded on $X$ in the sense of the first definition, and that $A$ is an arbitrary non-empty subset of $X.$ Consider the set $P$ of finite sequences $\langle s_n\rangle_{n=1}^k$ of elements of $A$ for some positive integer $k$ which have the property that $s_{i+1}\:R\:s_i$ for every $i$ such that $1\leq i<k.$
We define a relation $\sqsubseteq$ on $P$ as follows: $\langle s_n\rangle_{n=1}^j \sqsubseteq \langle t_n\rangle_{n=1}^k$ means that $j\leq k$ and $s_n=t_n$ whenever $1\leq n\leq j.$ The relation $\sqsubseteq$ can readily be verified to be a partial order (reflexive, antisymmetric, and transitive) on $P$.
Now consider any subset $C$ of $P$ that is totally ordered by $\sqsubseteq$. Observe that if $C$ were infinite, then we could use its elements to construct an infinite sequence $\langle x_n\rangle_{n=1}^\infty$ of elements of $A$ (so of $X$) with the property that $x_{n+1}\:R\:x_n$ for all $n,$ contradicting the first definition. Therefore, $C$ must be finite, and since $C$ was an arbitrary subset of $P$ that was totally ordered by $\sqsubseteq,$ then all such subsets must be finite. Hence, by the Choice Principle, $P$ has a $\sqsupset$-minimal element, say $\langle s_n\rangle_{n=1}^j.$ Then $s_j$ is necessarily the desired example of an $R$-minimal element in $A,$ for if not, we could define an element $\langle t_n\rangle_{n=1}^{j+1}$ of $P$ such that $\langle s_n\rangle_{n=1}^j\sqsubset\langle t_n\rangle_{n=1}^{j+1},$ or $\langle t_n\rangle_{n=1}^{j+1}\sqsupset\langle s_n\rangle_{n=1}^j,$ which contradicts the $\sqsupset$-minimality of $\langle s_n\rangle_{n=1}^j$ in $P.$ $\Box$
I leave the details of the outline above to you to verify, but the upshot of the above result is that the third definition implies the first, and is equivalent to the first as long as we have a sufficiently strong Choice Principle to take for granted.
To see that the second and third definitions are equivalent, note that a subset $S$ of $X$ is proper if and only if its complement $X\setminus S$ is a non-empty subset of $X,$ and that the following statements are equivalent to each other: $$\forall x\in X,\bigl[\forall y\in X,(y\:R\:x\implies y\in S)\implies x\in S\bigr]\\\forall x\in X,\bigl[x\in S\vee\neg\forall y\in X,(y\:R\:x\implies y\in S)\bigr]\\\forall x\in X,\Bigl[x\in S\vee\neg\forall y\in X,\bigl(y\in S\vee\neg [y\:R\:x]\bigr)\Bigr]\\\forall x\in X,\Bigl[x\in S\vee\exists y\in X:\neg\bigl(y\in S\vee\neg [y\:R\:x]\bigr)\Bigr]\\\forall x\in X,\bigl[x\in S\vee\exists y\in X:(y\notin S\wedge y\:R\:x)\bigr]\\\forall x\in X\setminus S,\bigl[\exists y\in X:(y\notin S\wedge y\:R\:x)\bigr]\\\forall x\in X\setminus S:\exists y\in X\setminus S:[y\:R\:x]$$
(Again, I leave verifying the details to you.) Hence, there is a proper subset $S$ of $X$ satisfying the first statement (i.e.: the second definition fails) if and only if $X\setminus S$ is a non-empty subset of $X$ satisfying the last statement, which is exactly that no element of $X\setminus S$ is minimal (i.e.: the third definition fails). Thus, the second and third definitions are equivalent, so the second implies the first (and is implied by it if we have a sufficiently strong Choice Principle to take for granted).

@downvoter, care to offer some constructive criticism?
